# Parsing certain kind of JSON data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I'm a little new to JSON and I'm having some trouble figuring out how to parse a JSON file that is structured like this:

```
{
"list1": [
    [
        "id1",
        "id2",
        "id3",
        "id4"
    ],
    [
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3",
        "value4"
    ]
],
"list2": [
    [
        "id1",
        "id2",
        "id3",
        "id4"
    ],
    [
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3",
        "value4"
    ]
]
}
```

I'm using the follow jQuery to get the JSON data:

```
var data = $.getJSON("jsonfile.json");
```

Example of what I want to do:

Get an item from "list2" for "value4", but I only know what "list2" > "value2" is. How can I parse the the JSON only knowing value2 and then get the value4 result?

I'm not even sure if I'm getting the JSON as a JS object correctly. Everytime I try to alert something from "data" I get undefined (except for when I do alert(data); it says [object Object].

Comment: [Here's a fiddle that demonstrates getting your object](http://jsfiddle.net/9GKdn/2/), But like plalx said, Not sure what your asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `$.getJSON` is async which means you need to do:

```
$.getJSON("jsonfile.json").then(function (data) {
    //use your data
});
```

The reason you get `[object Object]` when you alert `data` is because `$.getJSON` returns a promise object.

> Get an item from "list2" for "value4", but I only know what "list2" >
>   "value2" is. How can I parse the the JSON only knowing value2 and then
>   get the value4 result?

For the above question I do not understand it... however you can access your lists and list items like:

```
data.list2[1][3]; //value4
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I guess I just wasn't doing it quite right.

About the question though. I guess I just have to run a for loop to for what I want to do.